# How to attach multiple actions to a popup template using Esri JS API 4.0

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api

I am trying to attach multiple actions to the popup template using ESRI js api 4.0 it does't throw any errors into the console but doesn't display the action either, I can attach one action to a template and it works just fine I'm following this [reference guide](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-PopupTemplate.html#actions).

Code: https://jsbin.com/moqajuwugu/edit?html,output

```
  // Add this action to the popup so it is always available in this view
  var measureThisAction = {
    title: "Measure Length",
    id: "measure-this",
    image: "Measure_Distance16.png"
  };
  var someotherAction = {
    title: "Someother Action",
    id: "other-action-this",
    image: "Measure_Distance16.png"
  };

  var template = { // autocasts as new PopupTemplate()
    title: "Trail run",
    content: "{name}",
    actions: [measureThisAction]
  };
  template.actions.push(someotherAction);
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problem in the fiddler you have shared. I get 2 custom options. I may not be able to see the image as the image is missing. But I get 2 tool-tips. According to the documentation, when the actions are <3 then Image and text is shown, when its >=3, only image is shown and the title is shown as tool-tip.

> The title of the action. When there are fewer than three actions
>   defined in a popup, this text is displayed to the right of the icon or
>   image representing the action. If there are three or more actions in
>   the popup, then this text is used as a tooltip on the action.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Popup.html#actions